# Can't populate object from table using thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I'm basically creating this web app and in there's a table where all the shipments from a user a displayed and if they press the button to process the shipment that shipment is sent back to the controller and logic from the service handles the rest.

My issue is that I can't seem to get the object that thymeleaf sends to populate at all. The current code I'm using is pictures below:

[image]

Can't seem to figure what I'm doing wrong with it. If anyone can point out mistake or even tell me a simpler or different method to send just the id for the order that would be really appreciated.